# Switch case or if php - sign category

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

i have a really simple task to do, but i guess i`m a little bit stuck.

I have to check if post title has certain word in it and then give it a certain category. One post can have multiple categories.

How do i do it?

Switch without breaks so it checks every possible word?

```
    switch ($title) {
        case ($pos = strpos($title, 'xxx')):
            $this->updatePostCategory($id, Admin_model::XXX);
        case ($pos = strpos($title, 'asd')):
            $this->updatePostCategory($id, Admin_model::ASD);
    }
```

Many if statements under each other?

```
    if (strpos($title, 'xxx')) {
        $this->updatePostCategory($id, Admin_model::XXX);
    }
    if (strpos($title, 'asd')) {
        $this->updatePostCategory($id, Admin_model::ASD);
    }
```

What would be best practice here?

Thanks :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your `$words`:

```
foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strpos($title, $word) !== false) {
        // do update
    }
}
```

You can even create some kind of lookup:

```
$words = ['asd' => Admin_model::ASD, 'xxx' => Admin_model::XXX];
foreach ($words as $word => $value) {
    if (strpos($title, $word) !== false) {
        $this->updatePostCategory($id, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what i was looking for :) Thank you very much! Works perfectly :>